# How did I confuse scopes of variables and pointers in goroutines here?

Tags: pointers, go, concurrency, scope

I am learning Go by writing a simple program that concurrently downloads sensor data files from a few http servers. The sensor data files on the servers are refreshed at regular intervals (30 seconds or 2 minutes, depends on the 'origin'). Downloading the data can take from 100ms to 10 seconds. So I read some configurations for each server (OriginContext). Then I start a controller for each OriginContext. Each controller continuously fires a goroutine that does the download etc.

I stripped my code down to a minimal example that somehow/hopefully still shows my intentions. When I run it, there will be two controllers, but somehow when they fire the doStuffThatMayTakeLongTime() methods they all refer to the identical configuration.

So, how did I confuse scopes of variables and pointers in goroutines here?

I am very new to Go and also this is the first time I try to use a language that uses pointers. Well, my shy C/C++ attempts are more than a decade ago... so I assume my confusion is with reference/value/dereference, but I can't see it.

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "time"
)

type OriginContext struct {
        Origin   string
        Offset   time.Duration
        Interval time.Duration
}

type Controller struct {
        originContext *OriginContext
}

func NewController(originContext *OriginContext) (w *Controller) {
        log.Printf("Controller starting loop for origin %s.", originContext.Origin)
        w = &Controller{originContext}
        w.start()
        return w
}

func (w *Controller) start() {
        log.Println("start() of", w.originContext.Origin)
        go func() {
                time.Sleep(w.originContext.Offset)
                ticker := time.NewTicker(w.originContext.Interval)
                go w.doStuffThatMayTakeLongTime() // iteration zero
                for {
                        select {
                        case <-ticker.C:
                                go w.doStuffThatMayTakeLongTime()
                        }
                }
        }()
}

func (w *Controller) doStuffThatMayTakeLongTime() {
        log.Printf("%s doing stuff", w.originContext.Origin)
}

func main() {
        contexts := []OriginContext{
                {
                        Origin:   "alpha",
                        Offset:   0 * time.Second,
                        Interval: 5 * time.Second,
                },
                {
                        Origin:   "bravo",
                        Offset:   5 * time.Second,
                        Interval: 10 * time.Second,
                },
        }
        for _, ctx := range contexts {
                log.Printf("Starting Controller %s.", ctx.Origin)
                _ = NewController(&ctx)
        }
        select {}
}
```

And this is some output:

```
2015/09/07 14:30:11 Starting Controller alpha.
2015/09/07 14:30:11 Controller starting loop for origin alpha.
2015/09/07 14:30:11 start() of alpha
2015/09/07 14:30:11 Starting Controller bravo.
2015/09/07 14:30:11 Controller starting loop for origin bravo.
2015/09/07 14:30:11 start() of bravo
2015/09/07 14:30:16 bravo doing stuff
2015/09/07 14:30:16 bravo doing stuff
2015/09/07 14:30:26 bravo doing stuff
2015/09/07 14:30:26 bravo doing stuff
```

There should be alpha and bravo *doing stuff*, but there is just bravo.

Comment: Try logging :  `log.Printf("Controller starting with context at address %v", originContext)` at the beginning of your `NewController` function. You should see twice the same address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on these lines:

```
    for _, ctx := range contexts {
            log.Printf("Starting Controller %s.", ctx.Origin)
            _ = NewController(&ctx)
    }
```

The variable `ctx` is reused on every iteration of the loop [as described in the language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements). `NewController` is passed address of this single variable on every iteration of loop. The program prints the last values stored in this variable (although that's not guaranteed, there's a race on the variable).

<kbd>[run example that prints &ctx](http://play.golang.org/p/8IxrXjeU3U)</kbd>

There are a few ways to fix this. One way is to change the code to:

```
for i := range contexts {
        log.Printf("Starting Controller %s.", context[i].Origin)
        _ = NewController(&context[i])
}
```

<kbd>[run it on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Y_7lU4bWPk)</kbd>

With this change, NewController is passed a pointer to the slice element instead of a pointer to variable in the function.

Another option is to declare a new variable inside the body of the loop:

```
    for _, ctx := range contexts {
            ctx := ctx // <-- add this line
            log.Printf("Starting Controller %s.", ctx.Origin)
            _ = NewController(&ctx)
    }
```

<kbd>[run it on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SmoUefDQCA)</kbd>

This option allocates a ctx on every iteration through the loop while the first option does not.